# How can I configure a play-slick-db connection with ssh config?

Tags: postgresql, ssh, playframework, slick, ssh-tunnel

This is my current db connection in play slick

```
slick.dbs.default {
  driver="utils.db.PostgresDriver$"
    db {
      driver = org.postgresql.Driver
      url = "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/testdb"
      user = "root"
      password = ""
      keepAliveConnection = true
    }
}
```

My question is, how will I connect to a remote db that requires `ssh` authentication?

Comment: I am not sure about postgres, but it's not possible in mysql, so workaround is just to set up SSH-tunnel like `ssh -L 127.0.0.1:3306:remote-server.com:3306 user@ssh-host.com`